# Calling angular js with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm honestly really new to angularjs and this might sound like a really stupid question.
I'm trying to place a md-list on my page:

```
function apply(list){
            angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']).controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
                    $scope.people = list;
                    $scope.goToPerson = function(person, event) {
                      $mdDialog.show(
                        $mdDialog.alert()
                          .title('Navigating')
                          .textContent('Inspect ' + person)
                          .ariaLabel('Person inspect demo')
                          .ok('Neat!')
                          .targetEvent(event)
                      );
                  };
                });
            }
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-list ng-controller="ListCtrl" ng-cloak>
                <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Now online</md-subheader>
                <md-list-item ng-repeat="person in people" md-ink-ripple ng-click="goToPerson(person.name, $event)" class="noright">
                  <p style="color:white; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225,225,225,.2); height:45px; line-height:45px">{{ person.uuids }}</p>
                  <md-icon md-svg-icon="social:android" aria-label="android "></md-icon>
                 </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
```

needless to say, it doesn't work..
i wanna be able to call the apply() function to compile the md-list. Usually its supposed to load on page start but i dont really want that..can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could imagine that you are not correctly initializing your angular application at all. You need to either have an `ng-app="App"` attribute somewhere on your page (e.g. on the html `body` tag) for automatic initialization or you'll have to manually bootstrap your angular application.

More information on the initialization of angular applications (automatic or manual) can be found in the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

---

Version of `apply(list)` with manual initialization. Make sure to remove the `ng-app`attribute completely when using this

```
function apply(list){
  // define the angular module to be initialized
  angular
  .module('App', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.people = list;
    $scope.goToPerson = function(person, event) {
      $mdDialog.show();
      $mdDialog.alert()
      .title('Navigating')
      .textContent('Inspect ' + person)
      .ariaLabel('Person inspect demo')
      .ok('Neat!')
      .targetEvent(event);
    };
  });
  // initialize the angular module (this will render the list in the end)
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
  });
}
```

Comment: i do have that tag..and yes, on the body tag too..
<body onload="loaded()" ng-app="App">

Comment: Actually, if you do the automatic bootstrapping using the `ng-app` tag but then call your `apply(list)` function later on it makes sense that nothing happens. You're initializing a new angular module then but aren't doing anything with it. Instead of doing the auto-initialize, remove the attribute and add the manual bootstrap code to the end of the apply() function.

Comment: i do get this on page load event:
angular.js:13550Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=ListCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
can this be the problem? :/

Comment: yep, that basically tells you that `ListCtrl` is not yet defined when Angular tries to load. The reason is that you define the `ListCtrl` only as soon as you call the `apply(list)` function. I'll update my answer with a version of `apply(list)` that should work for your case.

Comment: just did, please make sure to remove the `ng-app` attribute, then try to use the apply function as posted above

Comment: okaayy..ive compiled the code u gave, but now other angular js stuff(which should load on page Load) stopped working

Comment: okay, umm maybe youre not getting what i'm trying to say..
all i need to do it compile the items of md-list in the apply() function..thats all

Comment: I see, so you got other controllers or directives defined on the module somewhere else, right? In that case, your easiest option is to switch back to the automatic initialization using `ng-app` but instead of defining your `ListCtrl` inside the apply function, you define it where you define all the other stuff. Now your Application should load but the list should be empty since there's no data. The only thing you have to do then is to load your data inside the controller itself instead of calling the apply function from outside.

Comment: sounds great, how do i do it? ._.
(im really a noob in angular js)